# Calculating Sentiment with Pandas - Looping Calculation is Slow

Tags: python, pandas, loops, sentiment-analysis

I have a pandas dataframe consisting of headlines. I am doing a simple calculation of the sentiment, by tokenizing and comparing the headlines with a list of positive and negative words. I am appending the over all sentiment for the headline into a column and then appending this to the original dataframe and saving as an Excel file.

The resulting and original files are about 12 mb. While the code below works, it is slow; and is taking me a couple of hours to fully read the file and assign the score. Is this normal? Is there anything I can do to speed up the process? I understand that loops within a pandas dataframe column may be slow - what are the alternatives?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import pandas as pd
from violencevocabulary import new_words as extended_neg_list
import unicodedata


#function to calculate sentiment
def sentimentanalyzer (country_name,text_type):

    data = []
    xls_file = pd.ExcelFile('/UsersDesktop/MasterData.xlsx')
    df = xls_file.parse(country_name)
    text_body = df[text_type]
    text_body = pd.Series(text_body)
    headlines = text_body.tolist()


    for i in headlines:
        if type(i) == unicode:
            i = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', i).encode('ascii','ignore')

            data.append(i)


    # processing the sentiment comparispon files

    pos_words = []
    neg_words = []

    f = open('/Users/positive-words.txt','r')
    plines = f.readlines()
    for line in plines:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        line = line.lower()
        pos_words.append(line)
    positive_words = pos_words[35:]
    f.close()

    g  = open('/Users/Desktop/negative-words.txt','r')
    nlines = g.readlines()
    neg_words = []
    for nline in nlines:
        nline = nline.strip('\n')
        nline = nline.lower()
        neg_words.append(nline)
    negative_words = neg_words[35:]
    g.close()
    negative_words = negative_words + extended_neg_list


    senti_list = []
    for j in data:

        tokens = word_tokenize(j)

        for k in tokens:
            negs = [k for k in tokens if k in negative_words]
            negs = len(negs)
            pos = [k for k in tokens if k in positive_words]
            pos = len(pos)
        calc = pos - negs
        print calc
        senti_list.append(calc)

    df2 = pd.Series(senti_list,name="Sentiment")
    new_data = pd.concat([df,df2,],axis=1)
    new_data_name = '/Users/Desktop/Results/' + country_name + " " + text_type + ".xls"
    writer_new_data_name = pd.ExcelWriter(new_data_name, engine='xlsxwriter')
    new_data.to_excel(writer_new_data_name,sheet_name='Sheet1')



    return
```

Comment: Most of these loops don't use Pandas objects, although you can speed up the `headlines` section by leaving it a a Series and using `apply`.  Also, you probably don't need a list comprehension for `k in tokens` inside a `for k in tokens` loop.